# How to show that the trace(A) is the coefficient of the $x^{n-1}$ in the characteristic polynomial of A

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, trace

I'm stuck with how to show that the trace of a matrix $A$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Comment: Do you already know about the Jordan canonical form?

Comment: Yes. Does it have something to do with similarity??

Comment: This could be trivial if you define the trace as the sum of the eigenvlaues

Comment: This is quite easy to prove using Leibniz' formula for the determinant.

Comment: Why is the trace the sum of the eigenvalues? And why is this the coefficient of the (n-1) term?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616930/trace-and-the-coe%EF%AC%83cients-of-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-matrix

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426006/tracea-coefficient-of-xn-1-in-charpolya

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Consider $\;\chi_A(x)=\det(xI-A)$. The $x$s appear only on the diagonal. Now the determinant is a signed sum of products of coefficients, each one in a different column and a different row, in all possible ways. As there are $n$ rows and columns, to get $x^{n-1}$ in such a product, we have to take $n-1$ coefficients on the diagonal, hence take the $n$ coefficients $x-a_{ii}$  and expand:
$$(x-a_{11})\dotsm(x-a_{nn}).$$
Now this comes down to one of Vieta's relations between roots and coefficients of a polynomial.