# Trace and the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace, characteristic-polynomial

**Let** $A\in M(\mathbb F)_{n \times n}$

**Prove** that the trace of $A$ is minus the coefficient of $\lambda ^{n-1}$ in the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

---

I had several ideas to approach this problem - the first one is to develop the characteristic polynomial through the Leibniz or Laplace formula, and from there to show that the contribution to the coefficient of $\lambda ^{n-1}$ is in fact minus the trace of A, but every time i tried it's a dead end.
Another approach is to use induction on a similar matrix to ($\lambda I-A$) from an upper triangular form, which has the eigenvalues of A on its diagonal, and of course the same determinant and trace, to show that for every choice of n this statement holds.

I think my proof doesn't hold for all fields, so any thought on the matter will be much appreciated, or an explanation to why this statement is true.

Comment: This is basically the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425082/how-to-show-that-the-tracea-is-the-coefficient-of-the-xn-1-term-in-the-char

Comment: It is, but im looking for a more detailed answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The determinant is a sum of (signature-weighted) products of $n$ elements, where no two elements share the same row or column index. From this, it follows, that there is no term with $(n-1)$ terms on the diagonal (if $n-1$ terms of a product are on the diagonal, then the last one must be too, because all other rows and columns are taken). So... the only term that can possibly include a power of $\lambda^{n-1}$ is the product of the main diagonal. Therefore, the $\lambda^{n-1}$ coefficient of $\det A$ equals the $\lambda^{n-1}$ coefficient of $\prod_i (\lambda-A_{ii})$ for which it's easy to show, the coefficient equals $-\sum_i A_{ii}$.

This definition doesn't make assumptions about the field over which the matrix is defined, because the field operations + and * are used directly (with no assumptions about inverses and distribution laws).

Comment: it seems that I lack the algebra, not the theory. I have reached the same conclusion, but failed to show that the $\lambda^{n-1}$ coefficient of $\prod_i (A_{ii}-\lambda)$  equals minus the trace of A.

Comment: It's similar, again you have all posible products of one coefficient from each term of the product. All those of form $\lambda^{n-1}$ take n-1 terms of $\lambda$ and one other term (there are n combinations, with different diagonal term each time).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$.  Then the factored form of the characteristic polynomial is
$$(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)\cdots(x-\lambda_n).$$

Try using this with induction on $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get how it is related to the trace of A...

Comment: Well start with $n=2$.  Then we have $(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)=x^2-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x+\lambda_1\lambda_2$.  So we see that the coefficient of the $x$ term is $-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)=-\operatorname{tr}A$.

Comment: but $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ aren't necessarily equal to $a_{1,1}$ and $a_{2,2}$

Comment: This proof assumes that the characteristic polynomial can be factored into a product of linear terms. This can be done over an appropriate splitting field but if one doesn't want (or have the tools) to justify the passage to such a splitting field, orion's approach is preferable.

Comment: You can use the fact that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$ and that for any matrix there is a transition matrix $B$ such that $BAB^{-1}$  is an upper triangular matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: @levap You make a good point.

Comment: You also use the fact that every Matrix is equivalent to a Jordan Cannonical form, which is a huge overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by proving that the characteristic polynomial is given by
$$
p(\lambda) = \lambda^n + (a_{11}-\lambda)...(a_{nn}-\lambda) + q(\lambda)
$$
where $q(\lambda)$ has degree at most $n-2$. **Hint:** Use induction on $n$.

Then it is easy to show that the $\lambda^{n-1}$ term has the trace as the coefficient.