# Show that all the eigenvalues of $M$ are positive real numbers.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive reals such that $b^2 + c^2 < a < 1$. Consider the $3\times 3$ matrix
$M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &b &c \\b & a &0 \\c & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Show that all the eigenvalues of $M$ are positive real numbers.

I wanna prove this without using quadratic forms if possible.

Attempt: Since $M$ is a real symmetric matrix all its eigenvalues are real, Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ be the eigenvalues of $M$, so $\det(M)= \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \lambda_3$ but $\det(M)= a - (b^2 + c^2) + c^2(1-a) > 0$, from here it's clear that at least one of the eigenvalue is positive, but how do I conclude that the other eigenvalues are also positive as well? from $\mathrm{trace}(M)$ I can't conclude that other eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: How about the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Okay, lemme try

Comment: $\chi_M (x) = x^3 -(a+2)x^2  +(1+2a-b^2-c^2)x - (a-b^2-c^2 a) = 0$ from here all I get is the sum of eigen values taken two at the time is positive

Comment: Shouldn't it be $2x^3$?

Comment: characteristic polynomial is monic 

Comment: Minimal polynomial is monic.

Comment: Yes minimal polynomial is monic but characteristic polynomial of M is $|xI-M|$ (or $|M-xI|$) so the coefficient of $x^3$ is either 1 or -1, Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I get $2x^3-2x^2+(2-c^2+2a)x+ac^2-b^2$, as the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: $-Trace(M) = -(2+a)$ should be the coefficient of $x^2$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616930/trace-and-the-coefficients-of-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-matrix

Comment: You're right. There was a mistake in my algebra.

Comment: How should I show that the other eigen values are positive? Any hints would be appreciated

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is
$p(x) = x^3  - (a+2)x^2 + (1+2a-b^2-c^2)x + (b^2 + a c^2 - a)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) the eigenvalues are real since $M$ is real symmetric thus you have $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2 \geq \lambda_3$

2.) the eigenvalues of $M$ (Cauchy) **interlace**  with those of
$M' = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0\\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$
which means
$\lambda_3  \leq a \leq \lambda_2 \leq 1 \leq \lambda_1$
Thus $\lambda_3$ is the only possible non-positive eigenvalue

3.) you already computed
$\lambda_1\cdot \lambda_2 \cdot \lambda_3 = \det(M)= a - (b^2 + c^2) + c^2(1-a) > 0\implies \lambda_3 \gt 0$

Comment: Wow! Cauchy's eigenvalue interlacing theorem is so cool! didn't know about this before. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that matrix $M$ is positive definite, which is guaranteed by if all the leading principal minors are positive. Indeed
\begin{align*}
& M\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 1 > 0, \\
& M\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} = a - b^2 > c^2 > 0, \\
& \det(M) = a - b^2 - ac^2 > c^2 - ac^2 = c^2(1 - a) > 0.
\end{align*}
This completes the proof.

Comment: What are the matrices after $M$? I have never seen that notation.

Comment: @LinAlg The matrix defines the rows (first row) and columns (second row) from $M$. Some used $M_{1; 1}, M_{1, 2; 1, 2}$ instead. I prefer to this notation as the $M_{1; 1}$ notation may refer to the submatrix instead of determinants.