# Show that A is a positive definite symmetric matrix using Gersghorin's circles

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matrix-calculus

I'm stuck solving this exercise and I need some help. Given the matrix
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha^2 & \alpha & 0 \\
\alpha & 2\alpha + \alpha^2 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & \alpha^2-2\alpha+2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
i'm asked to find the values of $\alpha>0$, using Gersghorin's circles, so that $A$ is positive-definite matrix.

As $A=A^t$, we know that all eigenvalues must be real. On the other hand, according to the Gersghorin criterion,
$$
sp(A)=\{\text{eigenvalues of A}\} \subset D(\alpha^2,\alpha)\cup D(2\alpha+\alpha^2,\alpha+2)\cup D(\alpha^2-2\alpha+2,2)
$$
And finally, $A$ will be positive definite if and only if all of its eigenvalues are positive. So I know I need to find all the values of $\alpha >0$ for the above to be true, but I don't know how to continue. Any help is welcome.

Comment: So you need to find all $α$ with $α^2>|α|$, $α(2+α)>|2+α|$ and $(1-α)^2+1>2$.

Comment: You can use Gerschgorin discs to obtain *some* values of $\alpha$ that make $A$ positive definite, but I'm afraid they cannot give you *all* such values. The correct way to find all feasible values of $\alpha$, I believe, is to use matrix congruence rather than Gerschgorin discs. Apparently, the answer is $\{\alpha\in\mathbb R:(\alpha^2+2\alpha-1)(\alpha^2-2\alpha+2)-4>0\}\approx(-\infty,-2.5163)\cup(1.3559,+\infty)$.

Comment: note: you could adapt the interlacing argument here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3872707/show-that-all-the-eigenvalues-of-m-are-positive-real-numbers/3872865#3872865 which tells you that $A\succ \mathbf 0$ *iff* $\alpha^2-2\alpha+2 \gt 0$ and $\det\big(A\big)>0$

Comment: @user8675309 Applying Sylvester's criterion to $A([3,1,2],[3,1,2])$ also gives the same condition you've got.

Comment: @user1551 Agreed.  I guess it felt like an Interlacing day today.