# Show that $Tr(A)=(-1)^{n-1} a_{n-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with characteristic polynomial:
$$\phi_A(t)=(-1)^n t^n + a_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \cdot \cdot \cdot +a_1 t + a_0$$

Show that $Tr(A)=(-1)^n a_{n-1}$

I think I have seen similar problems like this one solved here but they are not focused on the trace of $A$ but on other properties of the characteristic polynomial of $A$

**My attempt:**

By the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem we have: $\phi_A(A)=0$, so:

$$(-1)^n A^n + a_{n-1} A^{n-1} + \cdot \cdot \cdot +a_1 A + a_0 I = 0$$

If we get the trace of both sides of the last expression and use the linearity of the trace then:

$$(-1)^n Tr(A^n) + a_{n-1} Tr(A^{n-1}) + \cdot \cdot \cdot +a_1 Tr(A) + n a_0 = 0$$

I'm not sure how to proceed next. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616930/trace-and-the-coefficients-of-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-matrix)

Comment: The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues which are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, so by standard results for roots of polynomials the trace is equal to the coefficient of $t^{n-1}$ (after normalising the leading term).

Comment: @kipf Are you sure? There are matrices that have no eigenvalues, so the trace can't be the sum of them

Comment: Every $n \times n$ matrix has a characteristic polynomial of degree $n$, so by the fundamental theorem of algebra must have at least one distinct root in $\mathbb C$. Every square matrix has at least one eigenvalue in $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

Triangularize your matrix in a field extension $\mathbb{L}$, you will easily find that $\text{tr} = (-1)^n a_{n-1}$ since neither of the characteristic polynomial and the trace depend on the field extension.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is defined to be the determinant of $A - tI$, where $t$ is the indeterminate. I suppose that the trace of $A$ is defined to be the sum of the diagonal entries of $A$.

I do not know how you define the determinant of a square matrix. However, I will give a solution that is independent of the definitions.

---

Before solving your question, I need a formula, which you might have seen.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Suppose that the $(i, j)$-entry of $A$ is $[A]_{i,j}$. Suppose that column $j$ of the $n \times n$ identity matrix $I$ is $e_j$. Suppose that column $j$ of $A$ is $\alpha_j$ (which means that $A = [\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n]$.) One can write
$$
\alpha_{k}
= [A]_{1,k} e_{1} + [A]_{2,k} e_{2}
+ \dots + [A]_{n,k} e_{n}
= \sum_{i_k = 1}^{n} {[A]_{i_k,k} e_{i_k}}.
$$
Hence, by [the multilinear property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4720976/prove-the-multilinear-property-of-the-function-det),
$$
\begin{align*}
    \det {(A)}
    = {} &
    \det {[\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n]}
    \\
    = {} &
    \det {\left[ \sum_{i_1 = 1}^{n} {[A]_{i_1,1} e_{i_1}, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n} \right]}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i_1 = 1}^{n} {[A]_{i_1,1}\,
    \det {[ e_{i_1}, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n ]}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i_1 = 1}^{n} {[A]_{i_1,1}\,
    \det {\left[ e_{i_1}, \sum_{i_2 = 1}^{n} [A]_{i_2,2} e_{i_2}, \dots, \alpha_n \right]}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i_1 = 1}^{n} {
    \sum_{i_2 = 1}^{n} {[A]_{i_1,1} [A]_{i_2,2}\,
    \det {[ e_{i_1}, e_{i_2}, \dots, \alpha_n ]}}}
    \\
    = {} &
    \dots \dots \dots \dots
    \dots \dots \dots \dots
    \dots \dots \dots \dots
    \dots \dots \dots \dots
    \\
    = {} &
    \sum_{i_1 = 1}^{n} {
    \sum_{i_2 = 1}^{n} {
    \dots
    \sum_{i_n = 1}^{n} {
    [A]_{i_1,1} [A]_{i_2,2} \dots [A]_{i_n,n} \det {[e_{i_1}, e_{i_2}, \dots, e_{i_n}]}}}}.
\end{align*}
$$
Because of [the alternating property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721453/prove-the-alternating-property-of-the-function-det), one can write
$$
\boxed{
\det {(A)}
= \sum_{\substack{
1 \leq i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n \leq n \\
        i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n\,\text{are distinct}
    }}
{[A]_{i_1,1} [A]_{i_2,2} \dots [A]_{i_n,n} \det {[e_{i_1}, e_{i_2}, \dots, e_{i_n}]} }.
}
$$

---

Okay. I am going to solve your question.

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$
\det {(A - tI)}
= \sum_{\substack{
1 \leq i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n \leq n \\
        i_1, i_2, \dots, i_n\,\text{are distinct}
    }}
{[A - tI]_{i_1,1} [A - tI]_{i_2,2} \dots [A - tI]_{i_n,n}
\det {[e_{i_1}, e_{i_2}, \dots, e_{i_n}]} }.
$$
Your question amounts to finding the coefficient of $t^{n-1}$ (of the expansion). You are invited to prove, that among the $n!$ (unexpanded) terms, there is **exactly one term** which contains $t^{n-1}$, which is
$$
\begin{align*}
& [A - tI]_{1,1} [A - tI]_{2,2} \dots [A - tI]_{n,n}
\det {[e_{1}, e_{2}, \dots, e_{n}]} \\
= {} &
([A]_{1,1} - t)
([A]_{2,2} - t)
\dots
([A]_{n,n} - t) \cdot 1.
\end{align*}
$$
Hence the coefficient of $t^{n-1}$ is
$$
(-1)^{n-1} ([A]_{1,1} + [A]_{2,2} + \dots + [A]_{n,n}).
$$